# Angular Material dropdown list

Tags: angular6

I have the following JSON object

```
{"locations":"'MO': {'WRIGHT': ['MOUNTAIN GROVE','MOUNTAIN GRV']}"}
```

which would translate into

```
{ state: county: [city, city], state: county: [city] }
```

I need to make a `mat-form` dropdown for the states, and once the state is selected a dropdown for the counties then a dropdown of cities based on the county selected. I keep getting the following error

> `"*Cannot find a differ supporting object ''MO': {'GREENE': ['SPRINGFIELD']}' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays*"`

my dropdown looks like this

```
 <mat-select placeholder="State"  name="stateNameOption">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let stuff of addressArray" [value]="stuff">
          {{stuff}}
        </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

any pointers would be nice, unsure what to Google to solve this, I'm sure there is a name for it.

Comment: Ok, now it looks like you have an object with a single key, `location`, and the value of that key is the string `"'MO': {'WRIGHT': ['MOUNTAIN GROVE','MOUNTAIN GRV']}"`, so you still have a similar problem, but have moved it down a level. My guess is you want something like `"{"locations":{"MO":{"WRIGHT":["MOUNTAIN GROVE","MOUNTAIN GRV"]}}}"`.  Then, `locations` would be an object that you could iterate over the keys and build an Array which you could then pass to ngFor.

Comment: I had it working back in angularJS with ng-options="state for (state, counties) in states" where i pulled the state with var str = data.locations;

    $scope.states = eval('({' + str + '})');

Comment: I have answered my own question. I must of messed up when converting from my old angularJS. I is making the object as I would expect now. Thank you for hanging in there.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the JSON object

```
 var statesEvalList = eval('({'+this.addressArray+'})')
```

this will create a properly form object with addressArray equals the JSON object from before.

Comment: I feel like I should probably leave this here for anyone that may run across this later: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!